# Using @View Child in component file getting undefined value of prime-ng paginator

Tags: angular, primeng, viewchild, paginator

```js
@ViewChild('paginator', {static: true}) paginator:Paginator;
```

this paginator is undefined when I console in ngOnInit function.

why?

I tried to print prime-ng paginator in component file with using view child.but it's getting undefined.

Comment: Did you try with static: false. Static true means it does not read any changes after first initialization

Comment: can you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: @KelumBandara, Yes I tried.

Comment: @Rajat, now it's not needed. I resolved this issue. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add any logic you want to perform inside of `ngAfterViewInit` callback. During `ngOnInit` the the template isn't fully rendered yet.

Comment: I resolved this issue. Thanks for your response.

Comment: what did you do?

Comment: I have added condition on paginator in template file.That's condition give a result as false.so that's why I getting undefined value in ngOnInit.

Comment: did you try adding it into `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Yes I tried. please do upvote of my question.

Comment: Mark it as an answer perhaps?